# Powershell Export-CSV error

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

Just wondered if you can help me please.  I receive the following error:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\PSScripts\CompassADStaff.ps1:33 char:20
+ $Staff | Export-Csv <<<<  CompassADStaff.csv -NoTypeInformation
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

My code seems OK but I can't seem to detect why export-csv generates the above error:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#-------- Object variables ----------------------------------------------

#OU's to search
$searchbase = "ou=staff1,ou=users,dc=home,dc=local","ou=staff2,ou=users,dc=home,dc=local"

$Staff = @()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------


foreach ($ou in $searchbase) {
$Staff += get-aduser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(mail=*)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))" -SearchBase $ou -properties * | select-object employeeID,givenName,sn,sAMAccountName,mail
}
$Staff | Export-Csv CompassADStaff.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help or pointers would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain there is data in $Staff when you try to export it?

Comment: totally as I have stepped through and a csv is created with the required data.  Its just that it errors.  Thanks

Comment: That code works fine for me. From what I can see, the error would be generated when $Staff is empty before the export.  As you say it is still exporting data, I don't know what could be causing it.

Answer (score 2):

This consistently resolved the same problem for me:

```
$Staff | Where {$_} | Export-Csv CompassADStaff.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, can you check for existence of data in $staff like this:

```
If ($Staff) {$Staff | Export-Csv CompassADStaff.csv -NoTypeInformation }
```